# How to Parse this object in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script, I received an object from the response, I need to get the attribute appMessgae out from this object?

response  object looks like this:
{"status":true,"message":"Call Succeeded.","appStatus":"received","appMessage":"Your application has been received and will be scheduled for review."}

I tried response['appMessage'] or response.appMessage, none of them work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function resptest() {
  const resp = '{"status":true,"message":"Call Succeeded.","appStatus":"received","appMessage":"Your application has been received and will be scheduled for review."}';
  const obj = JSON.parse(resp);
  Logger.log(obj.message);
}

Execution log
3:07:47 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:07:49 PM  Info    Call Succeeded.
3:07:49 PM  Notice  Execution completed

function resptest() {
  const resp = '{"status":true,"message":"Call Succeeded.","appStatus":"received","appMessage":"Your application has been received and will be scheduled for review."}';
  const obj = JSON.parse(resp);
  Logger.log(obj.appMessage);
}

Execution log
3:09:33 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:09:33 PM  Info    Your application has been received and will be scheduled for review.
3:09:34 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```